# What are the meanings of 「って」, 「とこ」, and 「ねえで」 in this sentence?

Tags: words, particles

Here is the sentence I found these words in.

> ここ数日**って** **とこ**は 夜も昼も**ねえで** つづけたんだから むりもねえが...

Especially the **「とこ」**, I'm not sure if I should translate it to be 'bed' or 'room' or something else.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are colloquial Japanese for `という`, `ところ` and `～ないで`. `ここ数日というところ` means 'around the last few days'.