# Meaning of nounってとこ

Tags: grammar, set-phrases

People are discussing the characters in a comedy show and one of them asks

> 高木ってとこじゃないの

From the context I'm guessing it means "You like Takagi, don't you?"

Again the dreaded って. Don't know if it means は or という here. とこ means "place", and when I put it all together I get "It's not a place called Takagi"/"Takagi is not a place". Arghh!!!

[This link](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/23562/what-are-the-meanings-of-%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6-%E3%81%A8%E3%81%93-and-%E3%81%AD%E3%81%88%E3%81%A7-in-this-sentence) looked promising but it didn't help in the end.

Comment: Are you sure it's not って**こ**と？

Comment: @AmaniKilumanga I first read it as こと too. But I looked again and it is definitley とこ.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are correct that it is a colloquial form of というところ. It doesn't literally mean *place*, but perhaps you can think of it as “in that *vicinity*”.

ってとこ is often used when you are pretty sure, but not exactly sure:

> Q: How heavy is that bag?
>   A: 5kg**ってとこ**だ (*I'd say 5kg*)
>
> Q: Who do you think she has a crush on?
>   A: 高木**ってとこ**じゃないの？ (*I bet it's Takagi, no?*)
>
> Q: Why didn't he give me credit for my work?
>   A: 自分だけほめられたい**ってとこ**だろう (*He wants all the praise, or something like that.*)

Comment: >>Who do you think she has a crush on? That was my first thought for what this was a response to XD

Answer (score 1):

From [Weblio類語辞書](http://thesaurus.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%A8%E3%81%93%E3%81%A0):

> **ってとこだ**
>
> （意義素）ある物事を説明し、要するにそうであることを示す表現。
>
> （類語）そんな感じだ ・ そんな雰囲気だ ・ そんなとこだ

From these definitions the literal sense could be rendered "It's at/about..."

- 高木ってとこじゃないの？

  Is it about(lit: "is (your mind) at") Takagi？
- 値段相応ってとこかな

  It's all about/at matching value to money

Comment: explanation added

Comment: @Ninj0r Where does it say that? The consensus here seems to be that answers in English to English questions are preferable, but not a hard rule. And that an answer in Japanese is preferable to no answer at all. (http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/822/is-an-answer-in-japanese-only-an-answer-suitable-for-this-site)

Comment: I am afraid that I fail to see the connection between ってとこ in Japanese and “about” in English. The keyword in the explanation you quoted from Weblio is 要するに, and I do not think that your translation “Is it about Takagi?” conveys this meaning.