# What is the pronunciation and meaning of 乙って?

Tags: words, pronunciation, word-usage

I was in the middle of reading a light novel, and I've come across "乙って" at least twice so far. I can't really figure out what it means nor how it's pronounced.
I found it in this sentence if that helps:

> 長々と説明乙って所だが、聞き捨てならん事を言っていたぞ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is Internet slang for お疲れ様 (where 乙 is meant to stand in for the オツ in おつかれさま).

The rest of the phrase, ってところ, is covered by [this past question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/29682/meaning-of-noun%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%A8%E3%81%93).

Comment: Thank you. So this basically means that 乙って is pronounced as おつって?

Comment: Indeed, that's right.

Answer (score 2):

This [乙]{おつ} seems the internet slang of おつかれ. It is typical in the internet. おっつ、おっつー sounds more cheerful to my ear. [乙]{おつ}  by itself sounds dr ier and colder without assimilated sound and the elongation.

You should look up the phrase おつかれ if you do not know.

So, 長々と説明乙 possibly means “Thanks for your long explanation” and he/she wants to critisize something with the compliment. If you find it unnatural in the novel, Please provide more context of your light novel.