# what does "toko" in "ii toko desu" mean

Tags: translation

what does toko mean in this sentence?

- tokyo ni ikitai
- tokyo wa ii toko da yo

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the meanings of 「って」, 「とこ」, and 「ねえで」 in this sentence?](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/23562/what-are-the-meanings-of-%e3%81%a3%e3%81%a6-%e3%81%a8%e3%81%93-and-%e3%81%ad%e3%81%88%e3%81%a7-in-this-sentence)

Comment: Can you read ひらがな?

Answer (score 4):

In some contexts, such as your sample above, *toko* is an abbreviation of *tokoro*, "place".